# Q: Call to member function on null - Freeform (Solspace)

Tags: php, plugin-freeform

I am running Freeform 1.9.0 and I have a small plugin that is supposed to save user submission id's to a custom user field. The plugin returns error when it runs after a new user submits a form though.

Here is the error

> Call to a member function getContent() on null

Here is the code

```
craft()->on(
        "freeform_submissions.onAfterSave",
        function (Event $event) {
            $submission = $event->params["model"];
            $isNew    = $event->params["isNew"];

            $submissionId = $submission->id;

            $user = craft()->userSession->getUser();

            $user->getContent()->submissionID = $submission->getId();
            $success = craft()->users->saveUser($user);

            if (!craft()->users->saveUser($user))
            {
                $errors = $user->getErrors();
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the article [handling errors gracefully in Craft](https://nystudio107.com/blog/handling-errors-gracefully-in-craft-cms)  it will explain to code defensively and what to do in those scenarios. Your `$user` variable is `null` and you can't execute functions on `null` variables